# Highlight blank cells containing formulas using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

The range `"C2:E" & lastrow`, `"G2:G" & lastrow`, and `"Q2:R" & lastrow`  contains a formula which is dynamically distributed to all cells: `"=IFNA(VLOOKUP($B2,CONTACTS,2/3/4/8/10/11,FALSE),"")"` wherein Column C returns the value in the 2nd column in the CONTACTS table, column D the value in the 3rd column, and column E the value in the 4th column, so on and so forth.

Now, I need to highlight all the cells in this range in RED using VBA if it contains nothing/blank, which means the vlookup didn't find anything in the CONTACTS table. The data is dynamic so there's no definite number of rows, and I don't want to format the cells that are not included in my data.

How will I do that? TIA!

Comment: Since you know `C2:E" & lastrow` contains formulas, is there a reason you can't use conditional formating on that range?

Comment: lastrow is dynamic. It doesn't have a fixed number of rows. And I don't want to format cells that are not included in my data. So that's why...

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal but the following should work. Change the sheet name as required. In theory you can drop the IsEmpty part if all cells have a formula.

```
Dim rng As Range

For Each rng In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:E" & lastRow)
    If IsEmpty(rng) Or rng = vbNullString Then rng.Interior.Color = vbRed
Next
```

You can also use SpecialCells with formulas to do only cells with formulas (test that formulas are present first, or error handle in case not found):

```
Dim rng As Range

For Each rng In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:E" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    If rng = vbNullString Then rng.Interior.Color = vbRed
Next
```

---

You can use `union` to combine the different ranges:

```
Dim rng As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For Each rng In Union(.Range("C2:E" & lastRow), .Range("G2:G" & lastRow), .Range("Q2:R" & lastRow)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        If rng = vbNullString Then rng.Interior.Color = vbRed
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution QHarr! I have tested it and it's working. But as what you've said, this is not the ideal approach so I guess I have to wait first if there are more ideal solutions (optimized code) for this before accepting. Also, I realized that there are other columns that need this formatting as well. I have updated my question. My apology for this.

Comment: The last version is pretty effective but always worth waiting a while to see what responses you get. Appreciate you taking the time to give feedback.

Comment: You're welcome. Please see my updated question which includes other columns. Still don't know how to edit you're code to cater the new requirement.

Comment: See edit. You can use Union to combine the different ranges

Comment: Great! It works! Will give it a few more waits before accepting. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: You should be able to reduce the number of cell to loop through by extending SpecialCells to .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlTextValues). The specific amount of the reduction would depend on whether a matching vlookup returned text or a number.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks for comment. If they are only concerned with formulas that return an empty literal string does it still make that potential enhancement?

Comment: Sure, if 90% of the formulas returned numbers and 10% returned zero-length strings then you would only be looping through 10% of the cells. The fact that failed vlookups are to be highlighted seems to infer that they are in the minority. However, an On Error Resume Next should be added of finding no text returned from formulas would throw an error.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I hinted at error handling being required. Hadn’t through the whole thing through as well as you though. Appreciate the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional formatting can make this task easier. Here's how to apply a CFR with VBA.

[excel-2003](/questions/tagged/excel-2003)[excel-2007](/questions/tagged/excel-2007)

```
with thisworkbook.worksheets("sheet4").range("C:E, G:G, Q:R")
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    with .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=and(iserror(--C1), C1=text(,))")
        .Interior.Color = vbred
    end with
end with
```

[excel-2010](/questions/tagged/excel-2010)

```
with thisworkbook.worksheets("sheet4").range("C:E, G:G, Q:R")
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    with .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=and(istext(C1), C1=text(,))")
        .Interior.Color = vbred
    end with
end with
```

[excel-2013](/questions/tagged/excel-2013)[excel-2016](/questions/tagged/excel-2016)

```
with thisworkbook.worksheets("sheet4").range("C:E, G:G, Q:R")
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    with .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=and(isformula(C1), C1=text(,))")
        .Interior.Color = vbred
    end with
end with
```

Comment: This one will format all cells in the row. I only need to format the cells until the last row of data, hence the `lastrow`. Also, if I change the values in other columns aside from column C, it was still highlighted even though it isn't blank anymore. I tried to tweak a little by breaking them down by groups of columns and editing the Formula from `Formula1:="=and(isformula(C1), C1=text(,))")` to `Formula1:="=and(isformula(Q1), Q1=text(,))")` for columns `"Q:R"` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

you could avoid both conditional formatting and loops

```
With Intersect(Range("C:E, G:G, Q:R"), Rows("1:" & lastrow))
     .Interior.Color = vbRed ' first color all cells
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers).Interior.Pattern = xlNone ' then un-color those with a numeric output 
End With
```